# Ros2 launch nodes in a specific order

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like know, if there is a way to launch set of ros2 nodes in specific order using launch.py file
Say, I have following ros2 nodes; node_1, node_2, node_3 and node_4.
I would like launch node_1 only after node_2, node_3 and node_4 are launched.

Any example or code snippets are highly appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413401/ros2-launch-nodes-in-a-specific-order/) by [TinyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39584/tinyturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you only need to specify the order, then launch will already respect the order you specify nodes in. But if you need to have node1 wait for until nodes 2, 3, and 4 are present and running then read on.

I'm not sure exactly what criteria you have for "when a node starts", so I'm just going to use the built-in events. If you require more specific start-up conditions, you may have to write your own event, event handler, and event emitter.

Here's my python launch script to have node1 started only after nodes 2, 3, and 4 have been started. In this example "started" means that launch has processed that action, and the `ProcessStarted` event has been emitted.

```
from rclpy.node import Node
from launch import LaunchContext, LaunchDescription, LaunchService
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.events.process import ProcessStarted
from launch.event_handlers.on_process_start import OnProcessStart
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    node1 = Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp',
                 executable='talker',
                 name='node1',
                 exec_name='node1')
    node2 = Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp',
                 executable='listener',
                 name='node2',
                 exec_name='node2')
    node3 = Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp',
                 executable='listener',
                 name='node3',
                 exec_name='node3')
    node4 = Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp',
                 executable='listener',
                 name='node4',
                 exec_name='node4')

    already_started_nodes = set()

    def start_next_node(event: ProcessStarted, context: LaunchContext):
        print(f'node {event.process_name} started.')
        already_started_nodes.update([event.process_name])
        if len(already_started_nodes) == 3:
            print(f'all required nodes are up, time to start node1')
            return node1

    return LaunchDescription([
        RegisterEventHandler(event_handler=OnProcessStart(target_action=node2,
                                                          on_start=start_next_node)),
        RegisterEventHandler(event_handler=OnProcessStart(target_action=node3,
                                                          on_start=start_next_node)),
        RegisterEventHandler(event_handler=OnProcessStart(target_action=node4,
                                                          on_start=start_next_node)),
        node2,
        node3,
        node4,
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ls = LaunchService()
    ls.include_launch_description(generate_launch_description())
    ls.run()
```

The three `RegisterEventHandler` actions will call `start_next_node` after the specific node has been started. Once three nodes have already been started, then we'll start node1. We could do something to look at which node actually was started, So if we needed node3 to wait until node2 to start, and node 4 to wait for node3 to start, we could do that kind of logic there.

Example output:

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [node2-1]: process started with pid [5499]
[INFO] [node3-2]: process started with pid [5500]
[INFO] [node4-3]: process started with pid [5501]
node node2-1 started.
node node3-2 started.
node node4-3 started.
all required nodes are up, time to start node1
[INFO] [node1-4]: process started with pid [5502]
[node1-4] [INFO] [1679095729.989045466] [node1]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[node4-3] [INFO] [1679095729.990325048] [node4]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[node3-2] [INFO] [1679095729.990340845] [node3]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[node2-1] [INFO] [1679095729.990431971] [node2]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[node1-4] [INFO] [1679095730.988866943] [node1]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[node3-2] [INFO] [1679095730.989625772] [node3]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[node4-3] [INFO] [1679095730.989626316] [node4]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[node2-1] [INFO] [1679095730.989626457] [node2]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
```

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2023-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TinyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39584/tinyturtle/) on 2023-03-20**:
Thanks a lot @ChuiV this is exactly what I was looking for!!!